# Attribute Error when importing SpeechClient from google.cloud.speech

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am trying to use Google cloud platform to transcript audio to text. I am stuck really at the beginning.

When I try to import :

```
import os
from google.cloud import speech
    
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'speech-333807-fbe7e537e3a2.json'
speech_client = speech.SpeechClient()
```

The error pops out:

```
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.speech' has no attribute 'SpeechClient'
```

When I try to import this inside python shell, the above error pops out right away after import : from google.cloud import speech. But strangely enough, when I import it second time, import goes ok.

Do you have any clue why this is not working?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to make the audio-to-text speech API work for me. You should try this instead:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech
```

It's maybe just a version issue.